# How to transfer data to another sheet based on cell value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the code below that returns "Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{ line: 22 file: Code.gs" and I can't figure out why.

This workbook has a vlookup(importrange in column B which triggers column "O" to change from a null value to "Received". Once that that particular cell = "Received" it should copy that row to the tab named "Received" and delete it from the Master tab.

```
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('New Menu') {
  .addItem('Run', 'doneCopy')
  .addToUi()
}

function doneCopy() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range=sheet.getActiveCell();
 if (sheet.getName()=="Master" && range.getColumn()==15 && range.getValue()=="Received") {
   var targetSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Received");
   var targetRange=targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
   sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
   sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
 }
}
```

Any idea what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('New Menu') {
  .addItem('Run', 'doneCopy')
  .addToUi()
}
```

There should be:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('New Menu')
  .addItem('Run', 'doneCopy')
  .addToUi()
}
```

Probably

Comment: I like that "Probably" part. 

Okay the error is gone but the data only transfers and deletes if I type in "Received". I have a formula in that cell that populates "Received" but that doesn't transfer the data over.

Comment: As far as I know changes caused by formulas can't start scripts. Even in your sample the script was meant to start via the custom menu `New Menu` > `Run`. Just put a cursor into a cell and click the menu.

Comment: Thanks and I thought so, I searched the web and can't find a solution around that.

Appreciate your help